# Change input scope for textbox programmatically multiple times on Windows Phone 8.1 app

Tags: xaml, windows-phone-8.1, inputscope

I am trying to change the input scope for a textbox in Windows Phone 8.1 app programmatically at runtime, but the change only works the first time.

I have this xaml page:

```xml
<Page
    x:Class="InputScopeTest.MainPage"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:local="using:InputScopeTest"
    xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
    xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
    mc:Ignorable="d"
    Background="{ThemeResource ApplicationPageBackgroundThemeBrush}">

    <Grid>
        <TextBox x:Name="textBox" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="53,117,0,0" TextWrapping="Wrap" Text="TextBox" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="302"/>
        <Button x:Name="buttonAlpha" Content="Alpha" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="53,229,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Click="buttonAlpha_Click"/>
        <Button x:Name="buttonNumeric" Content="Numeric" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="246,229,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Click="buttonNumeric_Click"/>
    </Grid>
</Page>
```

And this .cs page:

```cs
using Windows.UI.Xaml;
using Windows.UI.Xaml.Controls;
using Windows.UI.Xaml.Input;
using Windows.UI.Xaml.Navigation;

namespace InputScopeTest
{
    public sealed partial class MainPage : Page
    {
        public MainPage()
        {
            this.InitializeComponent();

            this.NavigationCacheMode = NavigationCacheMode.Required;
        }

        protected override void OnNavigatedTo(NavigationEventArgs e)
        {
        }

        private void buttonAlpha_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            InputScope scope = new InputScope();
            InputScopeName name = new InputScopeName();

            name.NameValue = InputScopeNameValue.AlphanumericFullWidth;
            scope.Names.Add(name);

            textBox.InputScope = scope;
        }

        private void buttonNumeric_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            InputScope scope = new InputScope();
            InputScopeName name = new InputScopeName();

            name.NameValue = InputScopeNameValue.Number;
            scope.Names.Add(name);

            textBox.InputScope = scope;
        }
    }
}
```

On both the emulator and a windows phone 8.1 device the input scope for the textbox changes correctly only the first time you tap one of the buttons. For example if I tap the "Numeric" button first, the input scope changes to a numeric keyboard correctly. But if I then tap the "Alpha" button, the input scope does not change to an alphanumeric keyboard as it should.

The above code is taken from [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/gg521152%28v=vs.105%29.aspx) and it looks that it only works if you change the scope the first time. The second time the change is ignored.

Am I doing something wrong? Is there another way to set the input scope for a textbox programmatically multiple times?

Comment: Very strange your code is working on windows phone 10 device but not on windows phone 8.1 seems to be a bug in windows phone 8.1 latest release.